# Linker errors when building unit tests in updated Swift 5 / SwiftUI 2 project

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, swiftui

I had a working project with XCode 12.4, and I recently upgraded to XCode 12.0. In the upgrade, my unit tests no longer link properly with my main target. I have checked the usual settings:

- On my App settings, `testability` is set to true for debug builds
- In the unit test settings, it is adding the App as a dependency
- It can compile (and the `@testable import App` resolves)

However the linker cannot find any symbols in App.

Is there anything I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: The most recent version of Xcode is 12.4 and there is a 12.5 beta version available. There is no version 14, yet.

Comment: Sorry got confused between xcode and ios versions ...